# print the hash outside the loop in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a file and then want to print the output outside the `while` loop. Is there a way you can do that?

This is what I am doing:

```
   my $booklistFile= file.txt;
   my $perlbook;
   my $javabook;
   my $cbook;
   my $data;

   open my $booklist, "<", $booklistFile or die "can not open the file";
   my %bookHash = ();

   while(<$booklist>)
   {
     ($perlbook, $javabook, $cbook) = split (',');
     $bookHash{$cbook} = $cbook;
     $data = $bookHash{$cbook} ;

     print $data;
   }
```

This would print the `$data` inside the `while` loop. Is there a way I can print `$data` outside the `while` loop?

Comment: [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#Access-and-Printing-of-a-HASH-OF-HASHES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only guessing what you try to do here. If I look at your code,
you have probably a file with comma delimited records containing
book titles?

If so, the snippet below would print all C books, which should be
on the third field on your input line, according to your 
 `($perlbook, $javabook, $cbook) = split (',');`

```
...
my $booklistFile= 'file.txt';
open my $bookhandle, '<', $booklistFile or die "can not open $!";
my %bookHash = ();

while(my $line = <$bookhandle>) {
   chomp $line;
   my @record = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;
   push @{ $bookHash{PERL} }, $record[0];
   push @{ $bookHash{JAVA} }, $record[1];
   push @{ $bookHash{C}    }, $record[2];
}

# print all c books alphabetically sorted
print join "\n", sort @{ $bookHash{C} };
...
```

Now you get your C books in sorted order after the loop.

The loop-part can also be written without repetitions by using a hash-slice:

```
   ...
   ...
   my @record = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;
   for my $category ( @bookHash{'PERL', 'JAVA', 'C'} ) {
      push @$category, shift @record
   }
   ...
   ...
```

Regards,

rbo

Answer (score 1):

Accumulate the output in a variable and print after the loop ends?

```
my $data;
while(<$booklist>){
    ($perlbook, $javabook, $cbook) = split (',');
    $bookHash{$cbook} = $cbook;
    $data = $bookHash{$cbook} ;
    $output .= $data;
}
print $output;
```